# two revisions one transaction

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

Is there a way to close the revision tracking, or force a new revision tracking context within a single transaction?

I want to do something like:

1. start transaction
2. start revision tracking
3. make some changes
4. start new revision tracking
5. make some changes
6. commit

My cod might look something like:

```
    try (Context context = new Context()) {
        context.put(Context.OPERATION, "seed_people");
        context.put(Context.ACTOR_ID, Actor.SYSTEM_ID);

        persistenceService.transact(em -> {
            em.persist(new Person().setUuid("001").setForeName("james").setSurName("johnson"));
            em.persist(new Person().setUuid("002").setForeName("jack").setSurName("jameson"));
            em.persist(new Person().setUuid("003").setForeName("john").setSurName("jackson"));

            em.flush();
            context.put(Context.OPERATION, "seed_events");
            // trigger new revsion here!

            var event = new Event()
                    .setCode("CHANGE_NAME")
                    .setServiceClassName(ChangeName.class.getCanonicalName());

            em.persist(event);


        });

    }
```

such that the data might look like:

| id | timestamp | actor_uuid | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1686293931595 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | seed_people |
| 2 | 1686293931619 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | seed_events |